# How to sort posts according to meta value?

Tags: filters, query-posts, meta-query

How can I sort all the posts according to their meta value? I am using the below code:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-stream',
            'value' => $_POST['category'],
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'post_type' => 'half-day-course',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Also, I want to display the rest of the posts, but sorted posts should come first.

Answer (score 0):

'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query so I think you'd want

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-stream',
        'value' => $_POST['category'],
        'compare' => '='
    )
),
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'wpcf-stream', 
'post_type' => 'half-day-course',
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

to display the rest of the posts I'd run a 2nd query and exclude the posts returned in the 1st query